# link and post user input to another pg in new window

Tags: asp.net, html, postback

I have a page in my site that has allows users to search for different items, and when they choose the item, the "link".text next to it changes to how many times that item has been loaned, and when they click on it, I want a new window to pop up and display this history. My problem is the item they chose from the first page isn't posting to the next page.

I've tried many different things. The asp:linkbutton does everything I want, except it won't open the link up in a new window! There's no target attribute for that element, like there is for  and  tags. I tried adding OnClickEvent="'open.window(history.aspx')" instead, but user input isn't posted. Seems like MS deliberately took out the 'target' attribute for controls that were meant to post back to your web site >_

I know there are work arounds to my approach, such as session variables, but does anyone have any ideas on how to do specifically what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wiring up the OnClick event of the LinkButton and in the event handler do something like:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 // Do your server-side stuff here getting the new window arguments.

 string windowArgs = "";

 string newWindowUrl = "Page2.aspx?WindowArgs=" + windowArgs;   
 string javaScript =
  "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
  "window.open('" + newWindowUrl + "');" +
  "</script>";
 this.RegisterStartupScript("", javaScript);
}
```

hope it helps!